# Define to Classes of C++ and then have them both have an instace of each other as privates

Tags: c++

Here is what I want to do. Say a have a class ClassA so I would have a ClassA.h and and a ClassA.cpp Then I would want a ClassB so I would have a ClassB.h and ClassB.cpp.

Then in the ClassA.h I want to have

```
class ClassA
{
public:
   ClassA();
private:
   ClassB myB;
}
```

and in ClassB.h I want to have

```
class ClassB
{
public:
   ClassB();
private:
   ClassA myA;
}
```

The problem here is that I need to include ClassB.h in ClassA.h and viceversa which will not compile because it generates an inclusion loop. How can I save this problem?

Comment: Lookup on forward declarations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: `struct Box { Box x; };`...

Comment: It's not just a compile problem - each ClassA instance contains a ClassB instance which contains another ClassA instance, and so on for ever.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!